# Bromwich contour integral

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to run this as a `standalone` project in Overleaf but it does not run to generate a graph like this.

[image]

Could anyone help with this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, cabin}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-eucl}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\small
\psset{ticks=none, labels=none, arrowinset=0.15, PointSymbol=none, linejoin=1,shortput=nab}
\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1pt](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psaxes[linewidth=0.5pt]{-}(0,0)(-6,-5)(5,5.2)[\bfseries\textsf{x},0][\bfseries\textsf{y},90]
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-140,50,0,-90,90,-135}](0,0){O}(0,4.5){D}(0.8;45){J}(4.5;-50){A}(4.5;50){B}(4.5;-90){N}
    \pnodes{U}(-6,0.2)(6,0.2) \pnodes{V}(-6,-0.2)(6,-0.2)\pnodes(4.5;135){R}(4.5;155){Ar1}(4.5;-130){Ar2}(1.25;60){epsi}(0.6;45){Je}
    \pstInterLC[PosAngleA=180]{U0}{U1}{O}{D}{E}{}
    \pstInterLC[PosAngleA=180]{V0}{V1}{O}{D}{L}{}
    \pstInterLC[PosAngleA=140]{U0}{U1}{O}{J}{H}{}
    \pstInterLC[PosAngleA=-140]{V0}{V1}{O}{J}{K}{}
    %
    \pscustom[linewidth=1.5pt, ArrowInsidePos=0.54]{\pstArcOAB[arrows=->]{O}{B}{Ar1}\pstArcOAB{O}{Ar1}{E}\pstLineAB[ArrowInside=->]{E}{H}\pstArcnOAB{O}{H}{K}
        \pstLineAB[ArrowInside=->]{K}{L} \pstArcOAB[arrows=->]{O}{L}{Ar2}\pstArcOAB{O}{Ar2}{A} \pstLineAB[ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsidePos=0.75]{A}{B}\closepath}
    %
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt}
    \ncangle[angleA=-135, angleB=-45]{J}{R}\nbput[labelsep=2pt]{$R$}
    \rput(epsi){$\epsilon$}\ncarc[nodesepA=3pt, arcangleA=-70, arcangleB=-70]{epsi}{Je}
    \uput[r](A){$ \mathsf{\alpha - iT}$}\uput[r](B){$ \mathsf{\alpha + iT}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The source of this code is listed below:
[Hankel-Bromwich Contour problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269684/hankel-bromwich-contour-problem)

Answer (score 8):

This is a reproduction of the original figure with two `\draw` commands and without libraries. The arrows are placed on the segments to make it easier to position them, and to avoid libraries. Maybe this compiles for you.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/arrow/.style={code={\draw[very thick,-stealth] 
    (0,0) --(0.5,0);}},declare  function={r=1;R=5;h=0.4;alpha(\x)=180-asin(h/\x);},
    s/.style={sloped,allow upside down,pos=#1},s/.default=0.5]
 \draw[very thick] ({alpha(r)}:r) arc[start angle={alpha(r)},
    end angle={-alpha(r)},radius=r] node[pos=0.5,above right]{$J$}
    -- pic[s]{arrow} ({-alpha(R)}:R) node[left]{$L$}
    arc[start angle={-alpha(R)},end angle=-45,radius=R] pic[s]{arrow}
    node[below=2pt]{$A$} node[above right]{$\alpha-\mathrm{i}\mathsf{T}$}
    -- pic[s=0.6]{arrow} (45:R) 
    node[above=2pt]{$B$} node[below right]{$\alpha+\mathrm{i}\mathsf{T}$}
    arc[start angle=45,end angle={alpha(R)},radius=R] pic[s=0.75]{arrow}
    node[left]{$E$}
    -- pic[s=0.6]{arrow} cycle;     
 \draw (-R-1,0) -- (R+1,0) node[right]{$\boldsymbol{x}$}
  (0,-R-1) -- (0,R+1) node [above]{$\boldsymbol{y}$} 
  (-90:R) node[below left]{$N$}
  (90:R) node[above right]{$D$}
  (0,0) edge[edge label={$R$}] (135:R)
   node[below left]{$O$}-- coordinate (aux) (45:r)
   (aux) to[bend left] ++ (60:1) node[right]{$\varepsilon$}
   (r,0)node[above right]{$J$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]